# Parsing XML performance issue Android

Tags: android, xml, image, parsing

I send a request off to our server and receive a response from the server.  The response contains information related to an image.  The server returns the image as a base64 string.  It is taking way to long (30-40 seconds per image) to parse out the data so I can pull the information I need to save and view the image. I am looking for suggestions on better ways that might help to speed up the process.  I am currently using a SAX parser and the slow down is when the .parse function is called.

Comment: use smaller images. different parsing methods are not going to speed anything up

Comment: You might also consider downloading the image file separately -- one request to get the XML data, and then a second request to download the image (as an image file -- no parsing involved).